# Hibernate: Does not insert data if entity field is null and db field contains default value

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, spring-mvc

The one of my field in entity looks like below:

```js
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
public class MyTable {
    @Column(name = "MYFIELD")
    @Getter @Setter private Integer myField;
}
```

In DB I've updated my table like below:

```sql
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD MYFIELD integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

When I tried to insert data into this table I fill all other fields except this one above **MYFIELD**. Hibernate will try to make a query where this field is null. Because of null I'm getting following error:

```java
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 insert into MY_TABLE
(MYFIELD) values (NULL) was aborted. Call getNextException to see the cause.
```

**How can I set up my entity so it supports and uses database default value if I do not pass it?**

Comment: can you share how to execute this query please?

Comment: probably your problem here it's that you are saving the full object MyTable, and the attribute myField its null, the hibernate create an insert with  myField=Null and the default value doesnt trigger. You could set in your java attribute by default to myField=0 or create an insert only with the fields with values

Comment: Try "insertable = false" in @Column Annotation.

Comment: i mean your code

Comment: @kswaughs I tried what you did mention and it works, thanks a lot :)